# Copying file to build directory through Gradle

Tags: node.js, spring, gradle, npm

I would like to add some of my `node_modules` inside the `build/resources/main/static` directory of my Spring Boot project.

Can I do this through Gradle v2 by adding some task in my `gradle.build` file?

I'm trying this (which is actually for Gradle v3) but it's not copying anything so far.

```
task copyTask(type: Copy) {
    from 'node_modules'
    into 'build/resources/main/static'
}
```

[link for Gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:copying_files)

Comment: How do you execute this task? Have you run `gradlew copyTask`? Why do you copy from src/main/webapp to build/explodedWar if the goal is to copy from node_modules to build/resources/main/static?

Comment: Yes, you are totally right, sorry. I just wrote above the example from the documentation. In my `build.gradle` file I adjust it to what I need. I updated my question with the proper lines.
I run `gradle build` (or `gradlew build`) in order to execute the tasks. Actually I am new to Gradle and not totally sure how to do it.

Comment: Well I run it with `gradlew copyTask` as you wrote above and after also adding a dot after node_modules/

`task copyTask(type: Copy) {
    from 'node_modules/.'
    into 'build/resources/main/static'
}`

It worked fine, and after adding this line `jar.depends copyTask` it is executed withing the build task.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So adding:

```
task copyTask(type: Copy) {
        from 'node_modules/.'
        into 'build/resources/main/static'
}
```

in my `gradle.build` and running `gradle copyTask build` worked fine.

Thanks JB Nizet!